# Trying to create table using execute immediate

Tags: oracle, plsql

i am trying to create a table using below code.

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
cursor c1 is select '''create table demo1 (demo varchar2(100))''' c2 from dual;
testvar  c1%rowtype;
BEGIN
open c1;
fetch c1 into testvar;
close c1;
execute immediate testvar.c2;
END;
```

but it is giving

ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
ORA-06512: at line 8
00900. 00000 -  "invalid SQL statement"

What is wrong in this code.

Comment: Get rid of the extra quotes around the statement.

Comment: You seem to be confused about the difference between a string literal and a string variable. A variable doesn't include the single quotes even when the value is assigned from a literal that does (must) have them.

Answer (score 3):

You need nothing more than except these 3 lines of code if you really want to do it dynamically using a `PLSQL` block. No need for selecting from dual .

```
declare
vsql   varchar2 (100) := 'create table demo1 (demo varchar2(100))';
begin
execute immediate vsql;
end;
```

Note: It does not makes any sense selecting create table statement from a select. If you have any other specific requirement, please mention so that people can help you here.

Btw, you block will work simplly once you remove the extra `'` as mentioned by William

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
cursor c1 is select 'create table demo1 (demo varchar2(100))' c2 from dual;
testvar  c1%rowtype;
BEGIN
open c1;
fetch c1 into testvar;
close c1;
execute immediate testvar.c2;
END
```

;